# How to parameterize DB referencing objects Oracle APEX 18.X?

Tags: oracle-apex

I developed an Oracle Apex 18 application (DEV) and subsequently migrated it to another instance (QA) using APEX's export /import functionality. I am using some db objects that I am referencing using schema name dot object name notation, since I do not have parsing access to that specific schema, within APEX. ( example x_1.name_table in DEV, exporting to y_1.name_table in QA)
MY DBA created the objects and granted the required privileges in DEV and QA , however the schema names being different are posing a challenge when trying to migrate multiple such db objects.
My Problem:I have to individually modify the referencing objects within APEX pages , after importing them into QA.
My workspace and parsing schema are different from my DEV schema ( all within the same instance though...)

Is there any way I can parameterize the referencing objects  and avoid the added work and possible errors when migrating, such indirectly referencing objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with synonyms.

On each relevant database:

```
create synonym name_table for x_1.name_table;
```

And just refer to your table as `name_table` within the SQL.